# Disabling the Perforce "Sync Progress" bar

Tags: perforce

I just upgraded to the 2012.1 version of P4V, due to critical bugfixes and suchlike. However, this new version insists on displaying a popup progress bar in a separate window every time I sync, which is really annoying and tends to steal focus at inconvenient times. Is there any way that I can dock or disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm resurrecting a very old question, but you can enable a parallel sync which doesn't display a progress bar.

Under  `Edit > Preferences > Server Data` Select **Enable paralell sync**

Hope this helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar shows up for syncs that take longer than 5 seconds.  There's no option to disable it, but you could file an enhancement request for it by emailing Perforce support.